# Unwanted shape in logo

Tags: logo, lettering

I'm working on a logo for a startup that makes tents. Here's my first concept (Their name starts with K):

[image: First concept]

The shape at the top left of the K is the shape of a tent. The problem (that you probably noticed too) is that this K kinda looks like a guy pointing to something:

[image: First concept fail]

Any suggestion on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry, but I didn't notice these things until you pointed them out, neither the tent, nor the guy pointing.  It just looks like a stylised K to me.

Comment: It doesn't look like a guy pointing to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how you got to that result, what were the premises and what the steps ...

If the company sells tents and the final decision is to put a pictogram of a tent in the logo, there are at least three fundamental aspects as a conceptual level and they refer to the functional aspect of a tent, knowing that this will be a temporary shelter place:

- **Stability**

[image]

- **Firmness**

[image: Firmness]

- **Safety**

[image]

I don't think any of these points is represented in the logo, unless they are tents for risk sports. At the level that it's now it seems more like a whimsical way of fitting a tent-like shape into a letter K.

---

My **personal** opinion is that instead of asking what the combination of the K and the virtual tent look, it's to elaborate a conceptual guideline for the new logo and start to create from there.

Actually you are lucky, the letter K itself is a formally settled character.

- **Stable**: has double point of support
- **Firm**: it's well seated at the base, nailed in the ground
- **Safe**: one of the few characters that simulate covering like a shelter

[image: K]

Comment: Superb answer. Close to a (free) consultation!

Comment: Free.....? 

Answer (score 1):

Like @BillyKerr I *never* would have seen "a guy pointing to something".
Even after you mentioning it, I, personally, still think it's a bit of a stretch.

Different people can see all sorts of different things in ambiguous shapes. There's nothing you can really do to combat that. Everyone has their own imagination.

I typically don't worry about it other than to try and ensure there's nothing profane or offensive which may be garnered, event remotely. Or, if a client indicates they see something undesirable (even if I don't see it).